# Where is the right place of the Data Access Layer Layer in asp.net mvc 4 Code First based app

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, code-first

I am following O'Reilly's `` `Programming ASP.NET MVC 4 Developing Real-World Web Applications with ASP.NET MVC `` and I've reached the point where I have to create my first real entity. This is the code snippet from the book :

```
using System.Data.Entity;
public class EbuyDataContext : DbContext
{
public DbSet<Auction> Auctions { get; set; }
}
```

But it doesn't get clear where exactly to put this class. I have one previous project build with EF Code First, but there we used `Repository pattern` and separate project to handle the data access. Now I want to do some learning on my own and I really like this book, but I know how important design patterns and good programming practices are so even though it seems logically to put this class in the `Model` folder created for me from the `Visual Studio` I want to be sure that I'm sticking to what is right.

There's no namespace which could give me a hint so I would really like to know where is the best place to put the entities (this is the first but there will be more probably as the book goes on)?

Comment: Put the DAL in a namespace that makes you feel good. A separate project or the same project. You can always change it later (and will no doubt do so multiple times as part of learning about what you are comfortable and/or dislike). Note that there is no reason to stop using a Repository pattern with a DAL - in fact, the DAL might *be* the Repository pattern. (I usually tend to merge the "DAL"/BLL with the real DAL provided by the ORM - or EF in this case.)

Comment: Well, maybe I wasn't very correct with my question. I know that there is more than one way to handle this. But presuming that I'm building very basic app, based on the MVC principles where is the place for DAL? For me - the `Model` seems like the right places, from what I've read and so on. But i want to be sure. I just mentioned the Repository pattern but this is not the case here and I wonder is it really right to put it in the `Model` or it's better to make a separate project.

Comment: Just do it - honestly, it's the best way here. You'll see what you like (or dislike) about one approach or the other. Refactoring should be a breeze with the correct tools (ReSharper is free [or at least very cheap] for non-commercial). Different projects may call for different patterns or levels of separation depending upon size and scope. One big advantage (and sometimes disadvantage) of separate projects is that each project is a different assembly.

Comment: Well, I've already put it in my Model and keep on with the book but I really like to learn good practices. I know it will work this way but I'm sure there is some established practices about this, most probably based on the MVC pattern and since google is not very helpful for now I try to find the answer here.